# Android gradle library project: package extra modules and jars

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-library, android-proguard

I have a library project and i want to create a library jar with my modules and libs. 
I have 3 modules : A, B, C. where A is the main one.

i'm trying to package all AND obfuscate it.

Iv'e tried this:

```
task jarRelease(dependsOn: assemble, type: Jar) {
archiveName = normalReleaseJarName
from('build/intermediates/classes/normal/release/')
from(project(':A').projectDir.absolutePath+'/build/intermediates/classes/release/')
from(project(':B').projectDir.absolutePath+'/build/intermediates/classes/release/')
}
```

but in this case the classes are not obfuscated.

I also tried to use the classes.jar created by gradle WITH proguard

```
ask to export contents as jar
task exportJarRelease(dependsOn: exportSdkDocs, type: Copy) {
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
into('outputFiles/libs')
include('classes.jar')
rename('classes.jar', 'MyJar.jar')
}
```

but in this case i cant find the B or C modules inside, but the classes are obfuscated.

I might also add that I tried using "-injars" with proguard and B/C classes path but I got "duplicate classes" (which make no sense) and B/C modules weren't in the output classes.jar

I call to you all gradle experts out there! there has to be an answer for packaging library jar with all the project's dependencies!

Thank you!

build gradle information you might want to know:

```
 release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
```

---

```
dependencies {
compile project(':A')
compile project(':B')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hello**, So I have an answer. 
Things I learned after searching for an answer for this:

1. a build type that goes through the proguard will channel all of your module dependencies through the proguard. Builds without the proguard will not include the extra modules in the build/intermediates/bundles/buildType/classes.jar
2. Dependencies jars will be in the classes.jar only with proguard enabled, otherwise they will be in build/intermeidiates/bundles/buildType/libs/     as a jar file.

---

**Tasks**:

1. When proguard is off we want to collect all the jars and package them, like so:

   ```
   task jarDebug(dependsOn: something, type: Jar) {
     archiveName = debugVersionName
     from zipTree('build/intermediates/bundles/debug/classes.jar')

     //Adding all Libs
     FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: "build/intermediates/bundles/debug/libs", include: "*.jar");

    for(File file : tree.collect()){
      from zipTree(file)
     } 
   }
   ```
2. get obfuscated dependencies jar:

   1. add this to your proguard:

      ```
      -outjars build/proguardOutJar/proguard.out.jar\
      -injars ../B/build/intermediates/classes/release/
      -injars ../C/build/intermediates/classes/release/
      ```
   2. collect them to one jar with task:

      ```
       task jarRelease(dependsOn: something, type: Jar) {
        archiveName = normalReleaseJarName
        from zipTree('build/intermediates/bundles/normal/release/classes.jar')
        from zipTree('build/proguardOutJar/proguard.out.jar')
       }
      ```